# How to properly define an edge set with an uncommon condition

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to define an edge set as follows: $\mathcal{E}=\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land T_{ij}\leq R \land \text{$i$ and $j$ are not jointly in $\mathcal{K}$\}}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is the set of vertices, $\mathcal{K}$ is a subset of vertices $\mathcal{K}\subset\mathcal{V}$, $T_{ij}$ is the travel time between $i$ and $j$, and $R$ is a travel time threshold. So, I would like to create an edge including all edges satisfying the travel time condition and $i$ and $j$ cannot be both in $\mathcal{K}$ at the same time. To better convey, if $i\in\mathcal{K}$ and $j\in\mathcal{K}$, regardless of the travel time condition ($T_{ij}\leq R$), $(i,j)\notin\mathcal{E}$. How can I properly write this notation?

While writing the question, I realized the following can be right, can it?  $\mathcal{E}=\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land T_{ij}\leq R\}\setminus\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land i,j\in\mathcal{K}\}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct, although you can simplify a bit because $\mathcal{K} \subset \mathcal{V}$:
$$\mathcal{E}=\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land T_{ij}\leq R\} \setminus 
\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{K}\}$$

Here are two other ways:
$$\mathcal{E}=\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land T_{ij}\leq R\land \neg(i\in\mathcal{K} \land j\in\mathcal{K})\}$$
$$\mathcal{E}=\{(i,j)|i,j\in\mathcal{V}\land T_{ij}\leq R\land (i\notin\mathcal{K} \lor j\notin\mathcal{K})\}$$

Comment: Thanks for the verification, Rob. I will prefer your second way which perfectly reads what I mean.